# Javascript hide and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom-events

The code below is my CSS file. What I am trying to do here is to hide the  `<div class="container navbar-more visible-xs">` when I am not selecting the nav button `<a href="#navbar-more-show">`. But when I select the nav button, the container navbar will appear. The problem here is I am unsure of how to hide the div class by default, it keeps appearing on my page and I want to have it to appear when i click a navigation button.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a[href="#navbar-more-show"], .navbar-more-overlay').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').toggleClass('navbar-more-show');

        if ($('body').hasClass('navbar-more-show')) {

          $('a[href="#navbar-more-show"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
        } else {
          $('a[href="#navbar-more-show"]').closest('li').removeClass('active');
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
```

```css
 body.navbar-more-show {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.animate {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar {
  height: calc(100%);
  max-height: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, calc(-100% + 69px));
  transform: translate(0px, calc(-100% + 595px));
}
.navbar .container:not(.navbar-more) {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-more-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.55);
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1029;
}
.navbar-more-show > .navbar-more-overlay {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-more-show > .navbar {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 295px);
}
.navbar-nav.mobile-bar {
  list-style: none;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}
.navbar-nav.mobile-bar > li {
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav.mobile-bar > li > a > span.menu-icon {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
.navbar-more {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: calc(100% - 69px);
  overflow: auto;
}
.navbar-more .navbar-form {
  border-width: 0px;
}
.navbar-more .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
}
.navbar-more > .navbar-nav > li > a > span.menu-icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  .navbar-nav.mobile-bar {
    display: block;
    max-height: 64px;
    margin: 0px -.;
  }
  .navbar-nav.mobile-bar > li > a > span.menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-more-overlay"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top animate">
  <div class="container navbar-more visible-xs">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-icon fa fa-picture-o"></span>
          Photos
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-icon fa fa-bell-o"></span>
          Reservations
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header hidden-xs">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mobile-bar">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-icon fa fa-home"></span>
          Home
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-icon fa fa-info"></span>
          <span class="hidden-xs">About the Boat</span>
          <span class="visible-xs">About</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="menu-icon fa fa-phone"></span>   
          <span class="hidden-xs">Contact Us</span>
          <span class="visible-xs">Contact</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="visible-xs">
        <a href="#navbar-more-show">
          <span class="menu-icon fa fa-bars"></span>
          More
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> Scroll to bottom to see contents in Result!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these following methods

```
$('#YOURDIV').show() // Show your div like display:block;
$('#YOURDIV').hide() // Hide your div like display:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it just sounds like you need to add code to hide the element to start with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".container.navbar-more.visible-xs").hide();
     // your other code...
}
```

Comment: im actually trying to hide #container navbar-more visible-xs by default. This still displays the navbar even though i didnt click on #navbar-more-show